# Can 決めてない mean "crazy"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Context: after the commander of a platoon (小隊長) says some apparently incomprehensible things, one of the soldiers whispers to another:

> 「こいつ、なんか決{き}めてないか？」

What is the meaning of 決める/決めてない here? Considering the context, I guess it could mean "crazy" or "lunatic". Is it correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「こいつ、なんか決{き}めてないか？」

If I were to trust your guess from the actual context, I think I know exactly what the phrase would mean.  The verb I am thinking of is more often written 「キメる」 rather than 「決める」, but that is not a rule, so here I go.

「キメる」 has a slang meaning of "***to take drugs***".  Thus, the sentence would mean:

> "Isn't he on some kind of drug?"

「決める」 has a few important meanings that have nothing to do with "**deciding**".  Read definition #11 from [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B1%BA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-475856) which says:

> 11 飲んだり食べたりする。飲食する。**また、違法{いほう}な薬物{やくぶつ}などを摂取{せっしゅ}する**。

meaning:

"To drink and/or eat.  To dine.  Or to consume illegal drugs."

Comment: I think a more colloquial version of 「キメる」might be "Is he high?!"

Answer (score -4):

No, it doesn't mean crazy. It means "he haven't make up his mind?"